# How to know the process numbers of all the background commands running in parallel

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script to run various processes in the background. I want to know how can I wait the execution of the script until all the background processes (which are running in parallel) have completed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ARRAY='cat bat rat'

for ARR in $ARRAY
do
    ./run_script1 $ARR &
done

P1=$!
wait $P1

echo "INFO: Execution of all background processes in the for loop has completed.."
```

Here I've used the variable `$!` which gives the process number of the last background command, but i want to have the process number of every background command running in parallel.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Use `wait` without any parameters.

Comment: Thanks, that works. But let say I still want to know the process IDs of background jobs. How do i implement it?

Comment: Add PIDs to an array each time you start a background job. `doJob &` then `pids+=($!)`

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve overall? You can probably do it much better using **GNU Parallel**.

Comment: I want to start (let's say) 3 background jobs and explicitly wait on each of them to finish..

Comment: ... because that will allow you to do... what? If you have to wait for all three anyway, how does it help to know one has finished?

Comment: the code snippet that i've shared is a small part of a script.. once i ensure that all background processes have completed, then only i want the script to execute the next set of commands..

Comment: ... so just use `wait` without any parameters as you don’t need to wait on each job explicitly.

Comment: okay, Thanks Mark !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wait for all children, you don't need to know their pids, just call `wait` without arguments.
From `wait --help`:

> If ID is not given, waits for all currently active child processes, and the return status is zero.

But if you want to list pids of all children for some reason, you can use:

```
jobs -p
```

Comment: Yes, `wait` without arguments works. But let say I still want to know the process IDs of background jobs. How do i implement it?

Comment: Use `jobs -p` to get pids of all background jobs. "children" means "background jobs".